# Time dependent removal from the head of a queue

Tags: java, time, stack

If I have `someObject`

```html
public class someObject 
{
 String objName;
 int removeTime;
 //---------------------------------------
 //Constructor
 public someObject(String objName, int removeTime)
 {
  this.objName = objName;
  this.removeTime = removeTime;
 }
        //---------------------------------------
}
```

In the `main`, I would like to add a few of these objects to the `Queue` and `remove()` after the `removeTime` has elapsed.

```html
import java.util.*;

public class App {
 
 public static Queue<someObject> s = new LinkedList<someObject>();
        //---------------------------------------------------------------

 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
  s.add(new someObject("Harry", 10));
  s.add(new someObject("Jimmy", 5));
  s.add(new someObject("Tim", 2));
  
  //print s.remove() if time(seconds) == s.peek().removeTime
  //print full remaining
 }
        //---------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

What is the best way to achieve the function to `remove()` from the queue with respect to `Time`?

Comment: [`DelayQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html)?

Comment: The `SomeObject` should be sorted on `removeTime`

Comment: Is using a queue a requirement?

Comment: The queue is actually required because it simulates serving a queue of customers at  a restaurant. `DelayQueue` seems good though.